# How to dump all fields of object with __slots__ in Python

Tags: python

I have an object with two fields and I want to be able to `str` it as a `dict`. I do so using the code below.

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

>>> str(Foo(1, 2))
"{'a': 1, 'b': 2}"
```

Now I want to optimize this and include `__slots__`. Adding `__slots__` removes the `__dict__`.

How could I achieve the same result as above while also using `__slots__`

```py
class Foo:
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

>>> str(Foo(1, 2))
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```py
class Foo:
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return str({slot: getattr(self, slot) for slot in self.__slots__})

x = Foo(1,2)

str(x)
"{'a': 1, 'b': 2}"
```

Not the prettiest, but since `__slots__` will drop the `dict` attribute to save memory, you could manually construct a dict by getting each attribute

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of the accepted answer, you can redefine the `__dict__` as a property.

```
class Foo:
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def __dict__(self):
        return {slot: getattr(self, slot) for slot in self.__slots__}

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

x = Foo(1,2)

str(x)
"{'a': 1, 'b': 2}"
```