# Is there a way to convert list of objects to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say that I have a class called Person with only 2 attributes, name and age defined as below. Is there a way to convert this list of objects to a dataframe like below in an automated fashion without me having to dictate the column headers (in this case, being exactly how those attributes are typed in the class)?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

person_list = [Person("Mary", 30), Person("John", 32)]
```

```
    name    age
0   Mary    30
1   John    32
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can convert the objects to dicts, then it's super easy. In this case you can use [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

```
pd.DataFrame([vars(p) for p in person_list])
```

```
   name  age
0  Mary   30
1  John   32
```

In other cases, for example:

- [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (especially nested or with slots), use [`.asdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict)
- Classes with [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__slots__), this should work:

  ```
  pd.DataFrame([{a: getattr(p, a) for a in p.__slots__} for p in person_list])
  ```

  *See also: [How to dump all fields of object with __slots__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56585621/4518341)*

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." >.<